# Selecting all textbox at once with javascript

Tags: javascript

In my work we have to fill a lot of textboxes to do some validations. After all, we need to erase all - one by one - to restart the process.

Has some way to erase all textbox content with javascript (the only one method we can use now)? A for loop maybe?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll()` then iterate over each element and set its `value`

Comment: By textbox you mean `<input type="text">` or `<textarea>`?

Comment: @acdcjunior I mean <input type="text">

Comment: `document.formName.reset()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put all the input fields in a form and then reset the form by the `.reset()` method.

```js
document.getElementById("reset").onclick= ()=>{
   document.getElementById("form").reset()
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input/>
  <input/>
</form>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

See an [example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_reset) on W3Schools or the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) on MDN

Answer (score 2):

If you want to restore the fields to their initial value, reset the form as suggested by [@dota2pro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56029420/1850609).

OTOH, if you want to clear the elements regardless of their initial value, you can query the elements using a [type (aka "tag") CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) via [`Document​.query​SelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
 and iterate through the elements as below:

```js
function go() {
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="a"><br>
<input type="text" value="b"><br>
<input type="text" value="c"><br>
<br>
<button onclick="go()">click to clear</button>
```

Note that:

- `document.querySelectorAll('input')` fetches all `<input>`s regardless of their `type` attribute.
- `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]')` fetches all `<input type="text">`.
- `document.querySelectorAll('textarea')` fetches all `<textarea>`.
- If you want to combine, you can use the [comma combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors#Combinators_and_selector_lists):

  - `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"],textarea')`

Answer (score 1):

You can get in different ways in javascript:

- By ID : `document.getElementById("id")`
- By class: `document.getElementsByClassName("class")`
- By tag:

  document.querySelectorAll("input")

or Jquery

- By ID : `$("#id")`
- By class: `$(".class")`
- By tag: `$("input")`

Read documentation about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: **This isn't answers the question.** The question was: *how to reset all inputs*, not *how to select them*.

Answer (score 0):

tru

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('input')].map(x=>x.value='')
```

```js
var clean = () => [...document.querySelectorAll('input')].map(x=>x.value='');
```

```html
<button onclick="clean()">Clear</button><br>
<input type="text" value="some"><br>
<input type="text" value="short"><br>
<input type="text" value="text"><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bellow code will select all editable text-boxes

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]:not(:disabled):not([readonly]))')
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have JQuery available, you can do:

```
$('input[type="text"]').val('');
```

Or, if you prefer native:

```
for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('input').length; i++){
    document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].value = '';
}
```